# Find an equation of the tangent to the curve $y=e^x$ that is parallel to $x-4y=1$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Here is the problem and my attempt at solution.

> [image]

**Did I do this question correctly?** It took me a while and I'm unsure about a few of the steps.

Comment: It seem all right!

Comment: Thanks for the good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is correct.

I would not have written dy/dx instead of y' but this is more of a preference.

[image: graphical visualization of soltion to tangent to exponential function]